# Joining two record tables on record created on date time - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, outer-join

I'm trying to join (full outer join) two record or history tables containing information on the status of clients. Each record has a date-time field when the record was created, as well as an old and new status.

**Table A**

| ID | A CreatedOn | A Status OLD | A Status NEW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 2/05/2021 12:00:00 | NULL | Hungry |
| 10001 | 3/05/2021 12:00:00 | Hungry | Sad |

**Table B**

| ID | B CreatedOn | B Status OLD | B Status NEW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 2/05/2021 12:00:00 | NULL | Active |
| 10001 | 4/05/2021 12:00:00 | Active | Inactive |

My desired result is a record table containing all status changes for each date time.

| A CreatedOn | A Status OLD | A Status NEW | B CreatedOn | B Status OLD | B Status NEW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/05/2021 12:00:00 | NULL | Hungry | 2/05/2021 12:00:00 | NULL | Active |
| 3/05/2021 12:00:00 | Hungry | Sad | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | 4/05/2021 12:00:00 | Active | Inactive |

The result of my query however, returns a table without the last record from Table B

| A CreatedOn | A Status OLD | A Status NEW | B CreatedOn | B Status OLD | B Status NEW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/05/2021 12:00:00 | NULL | Hungry | 2/05/2021 12:00:00 | NULL | Active |
| 3/05/2021 12:00:00 | Hungry | Sad | NULL | NULL | NULL |

What I have isn't complicated... but I have no idea why it's not working.

```
SELECT *
FROM  A
FULL OUTER JOIN B
  ON A.A_CreatedOn = B.B_CreatedOn
```

My full query looks similar to this

```
SELECT 
 [A_CreatedOn] 
 ,[Status A OLD]
 ,[Status A NEW]
 ,[B_CreatedOn]
 ,[Status B OLD]
 ,[Status B NEW]      
FROM  A
FULL OUTER JOIN B
  ON A.A_CreatedOn = B.B_CreatedOn
JOIN C
 ON A.ID = C.ID
WHERE C = '10001'
```

Comment: What is `not working` ? What is the result of your query ? Is the `CreatedOn` date in both table are exactly the same up to the millisecond ?

Comment: Just edited the question. 
I'm not getting the last record from Table B

Comment: Please do not show structure and data in pictures.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that query. It should return the expected result. See [dbfillde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a61da1708f0a463633bfb9a6d3b1b4de). Are you posting the complete query ?

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: No. There is another JOIN and WHERE clause. 

I'll post the full query.

Comment: that extra `JOIN` and `WHERE` is affecting the result that you want.

Comment: `A.ID = C.ID` definitly excludes null `A.ID`

Comment: Do I need to have an AND in there.. 
```A.ID = C.ID``` AND ```B.ID = C.ID```
?

Comment: You didn't tell us anything about `C` at all. No idea what is the purpose of `C` and what you want to achieve with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `JOIN` condition because with `FULL JOIN` you can have `NULL`'s in `ID` of `Table A`

You can use this JOIN condition to solve the problem

```
JOIN C ON ISNULL(A.ID, B.ID) = C.ID
WHERE C = '10001'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JOIN C
 ON A.ID = C.ID
WHERE C = '10001'
```

The problem should lie in this condition. Check the join condition of this place.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. 
```JOIN C
 ON A.ID = C.ID OR B.ID = C.ID

WHERE C = '10001'```

Comment: if you required matching `ID` from both the table, why don't you put that in the `FULL OUTER JOIN` condition ? `ON A.A_CreatedOn = B.B_CreatedOn AND A.ID = B.ID`